# Using 'ws' for Node.js, how do I can I get a clients information?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I've set up a simple WebSocket Server using ws for Node.js

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ 
    port: 8080 
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(conn) {

    conn.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('<--', message);
    });

    conn.send('something');
});


// Console will print the message
console.log('-=-=- Server running :8080 -=-=-');
```

I'm trying to figure out how ws keeps track of it's clients. For instance, how would I get the clients IP address? I've tried `conn.address`, `conn.headers.host`, and `conn.IncomingMessage.headers.host` (I used util.inspect on the conn object to see the structure. But there's ALOT of metadata)

Basically, I'm trying to `console.log(conn.IpAdress)` in the `wss.on('connection'...` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
wss.on('connection', function(con) {

console.log('New websocket connection from'+con._socket.remoteAddress+"and"+ con._socket.remotePort);
}
```

Comment: great and git hub documentation

Comment: I combed through that for 2 hours. Where did you get the clue?